# Android Studio: Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I use my Android Studio to import an existing project, I just got a message below:

> Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy,
>   please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.

I've read many articles here but the problem couldn't be solved. I'm using Android Studio 2.1. Anyone here have a solution?